how to only get the numbers to solve an equation in qt widget?
I want to write an equation in one text edit and show the result in another. For example, in one text edit, I write:
(3x2+5x-6)
How do I only get the numbers in the equation above to solve the equation?
This is what I have written so far.
void MainWindow::on_input_textChanged()
{
    float X =ui->x_value->toPlainText().toFloat();
    QString z=ui->input->toPlainText().;
   // float r= a*x*x + b*x + c;
   // ui->result->setPlainText(QString::number(r));
}

X is the value set for x in equation, and z is the equation.
x_value is the text edit to get X value and input  is the text edit for quadratic equation.
result is where the result is shown in another text edit.
r is supposed to be the final answer for equation.
How do I only get the numbers in equation or z?
Edited:
this is what I came up with so far:
    QString z=ui->input->toPlainText();

    QList<QList<QString>> myList;
    myList.append(z.split("x2"));
    QString s1 = myList.at(0).at(0);
    float a =s1.toFloat();

    z.removeAt(s1);
    z.remove("x2");

    QList<QList<QString>> myList2;
    myList2.append(z.split("x"));
    QString s2 = myList2.at(0).at(0);
    float b=s2.toFloat();

    z.remove(s2);
    z.remove("x");

    float c=z.toFloat();
    float r=a*x*x+b*x+c;

but the problem is z.removeAt(s1); and z.remove(s2); will delete all the similar numbers to s1 and s2.
any idea how to fix this problem?

use three text fields and make them enter the coefficients seperately. It is confusing an error prone to let the user enter things merely to ignore it.

you can not convert this string to float directly. split it and store int value inside vector of int. https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

how do I split and store the int value?

If you insist on entering equations, the answer strongly depends on how flexible you want to be. It can go from a few simple .indexOf() calls to a regular expression all the way to a custom polynomial parser.

Concerning the "custom polynomial parser"... FYI: How to rearrange a string equation?

Oh, I was thinking even more evil than that: (x-1)*(5 + 9x3 - 7x2)

If you want to restrict the input to numbers, you may want to implement a drop-down list of digits/numbers or have a number widget with buttons for each digit, like a calculator application.

Use QRegularExpression to parse the desired arguments.
here is regex for taking only a,b,c coefficients of equation.
([^x]-?\d+)|(\d+)x
